# Conditional values based on the amount of rows for each id

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Table:

```
id
1
1
1
2
2
3
3
3
3
3
```

Here is the logic that needs to be applied:

1. For any ID >= 3 rows, the weight should be 1.15. If it doesn't satisfy this condition, the weight should be 1.0

Updated Table:

```
id   weight
1   1.15
1   1.15
1   1.15
2   1.0
2   1.0
3   1.15
3   1.15
3   1.15
3   1.15
3   1.15
```

Now, my first and only thought was:

1. Leverage groupBy to get counts for each ID
2. Merge this new dataframe with my original table.
3. Add a new column using a `when` clause.

I'm rather new to Scala so I'm not sure if there is a more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performing a `groupBy` will require a table `join` (or re-flattening via `explode`) before assigning weights for what you need. It would be easier to just assign weights based on the count by "id" over a `Window` partition:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df = Seq(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3).toDF("id")

df.withColumn("count", count("*").over(Window.partitionBy("id")))
  .withColumn("weight", when($"count" >= 3, 1.15).otherwise(1.0))
  .show
+---+-----+------+
| id|count|weight|
+---+-----+------+
|  1|    3|  1.15|
|  1|    3|  1.15|
|  1|    3|  1.15|
|  3|    5|  1.15|
|  3|    5|  1.15|
|  3|    5|  1.15|
|  3|    5|  1.15|
|  3|    5|  1.15|
|  2|    2|   1.0|
|  2|    2|   1.0|
+---+-----+------+
```